# What is a pseudo wave and how to calculate it?

Tags: orbitals, density-functional-theory, density-of-states

In a description of the density of states in 
https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/gpaw/documentation/pdos/pdos.html
I find the term pseudo (partial) wave (in the section Molecular Orbital PDOS). What is it and is it connected to an effective potential?

Comment: How familiar are you with basis functions & Kohn-Sham?

Comment: 11 months is long for no answer: try copy and paste into https://materials.stackexchange.com